# Mkdir() in the absolute path

Tags: php, linux

I have a rather interesting question that seems simple to answer, yet I have searched and cannot find the proper answer.  I am wanting to create a directory using mkdir() into the root directory of my website.  How can this be done if the PHP file that I am using is inside a subdirectory folder (due to project constraints)?

I've tried several variations like putting a " . " before the directory name.

Thanks,
drummer392

Comment: It is not interesting at all... :-(

Comment: did you try an absolute path? e.g. `mkdir('/home/user/public_html/new_dir')`

Comment: @aletzo: the next (and correct) question will be "how to get the absolute path" ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, and I know it's not interesting, but I am just having a blast over here!

Comment: A single dot (`.`) refers to the current directory, whereas two dots (`..`)  refer to the parent directory, which is what you want.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen, thanks for that bit of info.  That really helps me alot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dir");
```